# video conference application

Tags: c#, video-capture, windows-8.1

Hay i am new in media and quite new for C# i am trying for a video conference application, i have almost done it but my problem is a dll of windows actually i am using window 8.1 and i am trying to use avicap32.dll to open and close my webcam but its not working well it start webcam only once after booting then after until i don't restart my computer it always shows a black screen i am attaching my code too for reference. Thanks in advance.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;
using DirectX.Capture;
using DShowNET;


namespace Video_Conference
  {
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for Form1.
/// </summary>
public class Form1 : System.Windows.Forms.Form
{
    private System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1;
    internal PictureBox picture_comming;
    private TextBox IP_textBox;
    private Label label1;
    private TextBox device_number_textBox;
    private Label label2;
    private Button button1;
    private Button button2;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1; 

    #region WebCam API
    const short WM_CAP = 1024; 
    const int WM_CAP_DRIVER_CONNECT = WM_CAP + 10; 
    const int WM_CAP_DRIVER_DISCONNECT = WM_CAP + 11; 
    const int WM_CAP_EDIT_COPY = WM_CAP + 30; 
    const int WM_CAP_SET_PREVIEW = WM_CAP + 50; 
    const int WM_CAP_SET_PREVIEWRATE = WM_CAP + 52; 
    const int WM_CAP_SET_SCALE = WM_CAP + 53; 
    const int WS_CHILD = 1073741824; 
    const int WS_VISIBLE = 268435456; 
    const short SWP_NOMOVE = 2; 
    const short SWP_NOSIZE = 1; 
    const short SWP_NOZORDER = 4; 
    const short HWND_BOTTOM = 1; 
    int iDevice = 0;


    Capture capture = null;
    Filters filters = null;

    int counter = 1;      


    int hHwnd; 
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32", EntryPoint="SendMessageA")] 
    static extern int SendMessage(int hwnd, int wMsg, int wParam,  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AsAny)] object lParam); 
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32", EntryPoint="SetWindowPos")] 
    static extern int SetWindowPos(int hwnd, int hWndInsertAfter, int x, int y, int cx, int cy, int wFlags); 
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32")] 
    static extern bool DestroyWindow(int hndw); 
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("avicap32.dll")]      
    static extern int capCreateCaptureWindowA(string lpszWindowName, int dwStyle, int x, int y, int nWidth, short nHeight, int hWndParent, int nID); 
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("avicap32.dll")] 
    static extern bool capGetDriverDescriptionA(short wDriver, string lpszName, int cbName, string lpszVer, int cbVer);
    private void OpenPreviewWindow() 
    {



        int iHeight = 320;
        int iWidth = 200;
       // 
        //  Open Preview window in picturebox
        //// 
        hHwnd = capCreateCaptureWindowA(iDevice.ToString(), (WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD), 0, 0, 640, 480, picCapture.Handle.ToInt32(), 0);
        ////hHwnd = 132190;
        //// 
        ////  Connect to device
        //// 
        if (SendMessage(hHwnd, WM_CAP_DRIVER_CONNECT, iDevice, 0) == 1) 
        {
        //    // 
        //    // Set the preview scale
        //    // 
            SendMessage(hHwnd, WM_CAP_SET_SCALE, 1, 0);
        //    // 
        //    // Set the preview rate in milliseconds
        //    // 
        /    SendMessage(hHwnd, WM_CAP_SET_PREVIEWRATE, 66, 0);
        //    // 
          // Start previewing the image from the camera
        //    // 
          SendMessage(hHwnd, WM_CAP_SET_PREVIEW, 1, 0);
        //    // 
        //    //  Resize window to fit in picturebox
        //    // 
        SetWindowPos(hHwnd, HWND_BOTTOM, 0, 0, iWidth,iHeight, (SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOZORDER));
    }
        else 
        {
        //    // 
        //    //  Error connecting to device close window
        //    //  
            DestroyWindow(hHwnd);
        }
    }


    void startOrStopCapturing(Capture capture)
    {
        btnStart.Visible = false;

        if (capture != null) capture.Stop();
        if (timer1.Enabled) timer1.Stop();

        if (btnStart.Text == "START")
        {
            btnStart.Text = "STOP";
            btnStart.BackColor = Color.Maroon;

            try
            {
                if (!capture.Cued) capture.Filename = counter + ".wmv";

                capture.Cue();
                capture.Start();

                timer1.Start();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error Message: \n\n" + ex.Message);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            btnStart.Text = "START";
            btnStart.BackColor = Color.DarkSlateBlue;
        }
        btnStart.Visible = true;
    }

    void preview(int deviceNo)
    {
        try
        {
            capture = new Capture(filters.VideoInputDevices[deviceNo], filters.AudioInputDevices[0]);

            capture.PreviewWindow = picCapture;

            if (btnStart.Text == "STOP")
            {
                counter++;
                if (!capture.Cued) capture.Filename = counter + ".wmv";
                capture.Cue();
            }

            capture.Start();
        }
        catch { }
    }


    private void ClosePreviewWindow() 
    {
        // 
        //  Disconnect from device
        // 
        SendMessage(hHwnd, WM_CAP_DRIVER_DISCONNECT, iDevice, 0);
        // 
        //  close window
        // 
        DestroyWindow(hHwnd);
    }
    #endregion

    internal System.Windows.Forms.Button btnStop;
    internal System.Windows.Forms.Button btnStart;
    internal System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox picCapture;
    private IContainer components;

    public Form1()
    {
        //
        // Required for Windows Form Designer support
        //
        InitializeComponent();


        //
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void Dispose( bool disposing )
    {
        if( disposing )
        {
            if (components != null) 
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
        }
        base.Dispose( disposing );
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code
    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
        this.btnStop = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.btnStart = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.saveFileDialog1 = new System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog();
        this.IP_textBox = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.device_number_textBox = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.label2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.button2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer(this.components);
        this.picture_comming = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
        this.picCapture = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.picture_comming)).BeginInit();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.picCapture)).BeginInit();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // btnStop
        // 
        this.btnStop.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.None;
        this.btnStop.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.System;
        this.btnStop.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(123, 56);
        this.btnStop.Name = "btnStop";
        this.btnStop.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(112, 32);
        this.btnStop.TabIndex = 11;
        this.btnStop.Text = "Stop Capturing";
        this.btnStop.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnStop_Click);
        // 
        // btnStart
        // 
        this.btnStart.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.None;
        this.btnStart.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.System;
        this.btnStart.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(123, 18);
        this.btnStart.Name = "btnStart";
        this.btnStart.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(112, 32);
        this.btnStart.TabIndex = 9;
        this.btnStart.Text = "Start Capturing";
        this.btnStart.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnStart_Click);
        // 
        // IP_textBox
        // 
        this.IP_textBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(69, 303);
        this.IP_textBox.Name = "IP_textBox";
        this.IP_textBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(161, 20);
        this.IP_textBox.TabIndex = 13;
        this.IP_textBox.Text = "127.0.0.1";
        // 
        // label1
        // 
        this.label1.AutoSize = true;
        this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 306);
        this.label1.Name = "label1";
        this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(51, 13);
        this.label1.TabIndex = 14;
        this.label1.Text = "Remot IP";
        // 
        // device_number_textBox
        // 
        this.device_number_textBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(336, 25);
        this.device_number_textBox.Name = "device_number_textBox";
        this.device_number_textBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(48, 20);
        this.device_number_textBox.TabIndex = 15;
        this.device_number_textBox.Text = "0";
        // 
        // label2
        // 
        this.label2.AutoSize = true;
        this.label2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(238, 28);
        this.label2.Name = "label2";
        this.label2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(91, 13);
        this.label2.TabIndex = 16;
        this.label2.Text = "Capture Device #";
        // 
        // button1
        // 
        this.button1.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.System;
        this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(336, 300);
        this.button1.Name = "button1";
        this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        this.button1.TabIndex = 17;
        this.button1.Text = "Listener";
        this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
        // 
        // button2
        // 
        this.button2.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.System;
        this.button2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(239, 301);
        this.button2.Name = "button2";
        this.button2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(91, 23);
        this.button2.TabIndex = 18;
        this.button2.Text = "Start Sending";
        this.button2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.button2.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button2_Click);
        // 
        // timer1
        // 
        this.timer1.Interval = 1000;
        this.timer1.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.timer1_Tick);
        // 
        // picture_comming
        // 
        this.picture_comming.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.None;
        this.picture_comming.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
        this.picture_comming.Image = global::Video_Conference.Properties.Resources.ip;
        this.picture_comming.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(15, 104);
        this.picture_comming.Name = "picture_comming";
        this.picture_comming.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(246, 189);
        this.picture_comming.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        this.picture_comming.TabIndex = 12;
        this.picture_comming.TabStop = false;
        // 
        // picCapture
        // 
        this.picCapture.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.None;
        this.picCapture.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
        this.picCapture.Image = global::Video_Conference.Properties.Resources.icony;
        this.picCapture.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(15, 18);
        this.picCapture.Name = "picCapture";
        this.picCapture.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(102, 80);
        this.picCapture.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        this.picCapture.TabIndex = 6;
        this.picCapture.TabStop = false;
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(414, 338);
        this.Controls.Add(this.button2);
        this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label2);
        this.Controls.Add(this.device_number_textBox);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.IP_textBox);
        this.Controls.Add(this.picture_comming);
        this.Controls.Add(this.btnStop);
        this.Controls.Add(this.btnStart);
        this.Controls.Add(this.picCapture);
        this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        this.MaximizeBox = false;
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        this.Text = "Video Conference - Peer 1 - www.fadidotnet.org";
        this.Closing += new System.ComponentModel.CancelEventHandler(this.Form1_Closing);
        this.FormClosing += new System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventHandler(this.Form1_FormClosing);
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.picture_comming)).EndInit();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.picCapture)).EndInit();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.PerformLayout();

    }
    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main() 
    {
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
    TcpClient myclient;
    MemoryStream ms;
    NetworkStream myns;
    BinaryWriter mysw;
    Thread myth;
    TcpListener mytcpl;
    Socket mysocket;
    NetworkStream ns;

    private void Start_Receiving_Video_Conference()
    {
        try
        {
            // Open The Port
            string i = "2.1.168.192";
            long z = (long)(uint)IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder((int)IPAddress.Parse(i).Address);
            IPAddress ip = new IPAddress(z);
            mytcpl = new TcpListener(ip, 6000);
            mytcpl.Start();                      // Start Listening on That Port
            mysocket = mytcpl.AcceptSocket();        // Accept Any Request From Client and Start a Session
            ns = new NetworkStream(mysocket);    // Receives The Binary Data From Port

            picture_comming.Image = Image.FromStream(ns);
            mytcpl.Stop();                           // Close TCP Session

            if (mysocket.Connected == true)          // Looping While Connected to Receive Another Message 
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    Start_Receiving_Video_Conference();              // Back to First Method
                }
            }
            myns.Flush();

        }
        catch (Exception) { button1.Enabled = true; myth.Abort(); }
    }

    private void Start_Sending_Video_Conference(string remote_IP, int port_number)
    {
        try
        {

            ms = new MemoryStream();// Store it in Binary Array as Stream
            IDataObject data;
            Image bmap;

            //  Copy image to clipboard
            SendMessage(hHwnd, WM_CAP_EDIT_COPY, 0, 0);

            //  Get image from clipboard and convert it to a bitmap
            data = Clipboard.GetDataObject();

            if (data.GetDataPresent(typeof(System.Drawing.Bitmap)))
            {
                bmap = ((Image)(data.GetData(typeof(System.Drawing.Bitmap))));
                bmap.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Bmp);
            }


            picCapture.Image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            byte[] arrImage = ms.GetBuffer();
            myclient = new TcpClient(remote_IP, port_number);//Connecting with server
            myns = myclient.GetStream();
            mysw = new BinaryWriter(myns);
            mysw.Write(arrImage);//send the stream to above address
            ms.Flush();
            mysw.Flush();
            myns.Flush();
            ms.Close();
            mysw.Close();
            myns.Close();
            myclient.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Video Conference Error Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }

    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        iDevice = int.Parse (device_number_textBox.Text);
        OpenPreviewWindow();        
    }

    private void btnStop_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        ClosePreviewWindow();

    }

    private void Form1_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (btnStop.Enabled) 
        {
            ClosePreviewWindow();
        }

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Enabled = false;
        myth = new Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(Start_Receiving_Video_Conference)); // Start Thread Session
        myth.Start(); // Start Receiveing Camera
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Start_Sending_Video_Conference(IP_textBox.Text, 6000);
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            mytcpl.Stop();
            myth.Abort();
        }
        catch (Exception){}
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Enabled = true;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: The fact that you're silently ignoring exceptions (both in your `Start_Receiving_Video_Conference` and `preview` methods) means that you're basically asking for such things to happen. Enable "break on exceptions" - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d14azbfh.aspx if you don't know how - and try running your code again. You might learn about an exception handled "deep inside" the library (and normally invisible to you), which could shed some light on your issue.

Comment: You should also use a `finally` block for releasing resources. If an exception is thrown in `Start_Sending_Video_Conference` before it gets to all the `ms.Close(); mysw.Close();`, they'll never get closed. Move your `Flush` and `Close` calls into a `finally` block to make sure they will execute regardless of whether or not an exception is thrown. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwc8s4fz.aspx for reference.